# JSON_VALUE() with CONCAT() get syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

Tested in mysql  Ver 8.0.26

```
SET @my_json = '{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}';
SET @my_key = 'key1';
```

Everything's okay with the following attempt:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@my_json,'$.key1');
```

| JSON_VALUE(@my_json,'$.key1') |
| --- |
| val1 |

Though with the following one I get an error:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@my_json,CONCAT('$.',@my_key));
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT('$.',@my_key))' at line 1

Also if I try these other two attempts:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@my_json,CONCAT('$.','key1'));

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@my_json,CONCAT('$.','"key1"'));
```

I am doing something wrong?

I need to use dynamic `key names` as `@variable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [JSON_VALUE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value) description claims

> *path* is a JSON path pointing to a location in the document. **This must be a string literal value.**

I.e. you cannot use an expression as *path* parameter.

Solution: use [JSON_EXTRACT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function (accompanied with JSON_UNQUOTE() for string-type data). https://dbfiddle.uk/UdJGwopG